# Prove: If $f$ is bounded and uniformly continuous on $R$ and $g(x)=f(x)^2$ for all $x \in R$, then $g$ is uniformly continuous on $R$.

Tags: real-analysis

My initial approach was to use the definition of uniform continuity and altering the epsilon since there exists $M \in R$ such that $f(x)\leq M$

I'm confused about the selection of delta in this process, if using the epsilon-delta definition of uniform continuity even is the right way of doing this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be great if you could show a formal attempt so that we can highlight where you went wrong and needed assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous and bounded, we know that:

$$\exists M \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: |f(x)| \leq M$$

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}: |x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then:

$$|g(x)-g(y)| = |(f(x))^2-(f(y))^2| = |(f(x)-f(y))(f(x)+f(y))| = |f(x)-f(y)| \cdot |f(x)+f(y)|$$

By the triangle inequality, wee can see that:

$$|g(x)-g(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(y)| \cdot (|f(x)|+|f(y)|) \leq |f(x)-f(y)| \cdot 2M$$

Then, we know that there is a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that:

$$|x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$$

Hence, let $\delta = \delta_1$. Then:

$$|x-y| < \delta \implies |g(x)-g(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(y)| \cdot 2M < \frac{\epsilon}{2M} \cdot 2M = \epsilon$$

which is exactly what we wanted. Hence, $g$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Does that make sense?